# Regex: match html input tag only if disabled attribute is set

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

So if we have:

```
<input type="number" disabled/>
<input disabled type="number"/>
<input disabled/>
<input type="number"/>
```

only the first 3 are selected.

So basically, I need to select an input tag if disabled occurs anywhere between "input" and "/>". But it needs to be an input tag.

I thought maybe a positive lookahead might work, something like `\<input\s+.*(?=disabled).*\/\>`. But this matches the string even if there is an attribute `disablednot`, which is not correct.

Then I tried `\<input\s+.*(?=disabled\s+).*\/\>`, but this doesn't match when `disabled` is the last attribute, eg: `<input disabled/>`

Comment: general rule is you shouldnt use regex for pulling info out of html, is there a reason you dont want to use an html parser?

Comment: I'm trying to contribute to a vscode extension, which targets many languages, not just html. The whole structure beehind the extension is made using regex. The question is much more simplified, but in the end, that's what I need to do.

Comment: You might exclude matching the tags inbetween `<input [^<>]*disabled[^<>]*/>`

Comment: Actually, it is going to be much harder. Something like `<input(?:\s+[^\s=]+(?:=(?:(['"])(?:(?!\1).)*\1|[^\s'">/]+))?)*\s+disabled(?=[=\s]|\s*/?>)[^>]*/>`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9YMrZa/2).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use HTML parser, you can try this regular expression.

```
<input[^\/>]*?(?=disabled\s|disabled\/).*\/>
```

You can find the demo and comments [here](https://regex101.com/r/SgEbX0/1)